# How can I make controls added to existing mark-up be automatically hooked up to the code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have an existing `page.aspx` with a bunch of controls:

```
<%@ Page Trace="false" Language="c#" Codebehind="page.aspx.cs" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="False" %>
<asp:CheckBox id="test1" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox id="test2" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox id="test3" runat="server" />
```

And a code behind `page.aspx.cs` that declares a protected member with the same type and name as each control in the markup:

```
protected CheckBox test1, test2;
protected TextBox test3;
```

When the page is created, these three members are automatically initialized to refer to the appropriate controls.

I then add a new control:

```
// In page.aspx
<asp:TextBox id="test4" runat="server" />

// In page.aspx.cs 
protected TextBox test4;
```

The `test4` member is **not** initialized. It remains null.

The only 'solution' I can find is to convert the page to a web application, which doesn't work in this case. It creates a designer file (which originally didn't exist for this) and removes all of the protected members from the code behind, breaking compilation.

How can I make it so that my new controls are hooked up automatically?

Comment: You must find how those controls are automatically getting hooked up and then do the same for newly created one.

Comment: Thank you for this enlightening comment. A text search of `test{1,2,3}` in the solution directory brings up no occurrences outside of the two files.

Comment: First of all, I don't see any need for those type of design and second, NO there is no magic trick to bind those runtime controls. There must be something behind the scene happening. Check with your team mates/someone who can let you know that. At this point without more info (which you as well don't know) I don't see how I can be of much help to you.

Comment: I've checked with team mates. They expect it to automatically be hooked up. Some other teams have encountered the same problem, but were unable to find a solution; which is why the question is now being asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: Is your project a website or a web application?

Comment: @Sam: It's a web application.

Comment: If it's a web application your aspx pages should have a designer file by default. But, if your project is a website then .aspx pages will not have a designer file and each page is compiled on the fly by VS compiler. there are few files being created by VS in following temp folder (path depends on your .Net Framework version) C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: Having said that you can create aspx files without a designer file by removing the Inherits attribute of the @Page directive. Then you have to initialize your controls by your self, which is not automated. It's worth trying a clean build.

Comment: @Sam: Deleting the temporary files fixed it, thank you. This is a little concerning.

Comment: It's a good practice to do a clean build once in a while. I've added my replies as an answer. Please accept if it resolved the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a web application your aspx pages should have a designer file by default. But, if your project is a website then .aspx pages will not have a designer file and each page is compiled on the fly by VS compiler. there are few files being created by VS in following temp folder (path depends on your .Net Framework version)

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

Having said that you can create aspx files without a designer file by removing the Inherits attribute of the @Page directive. Then you have to initialize your controls by your self, which is not automated. It's worth trying a clean build.